# How to use modules in racket?

Tags: file, unit-testing, module, racket

I want to separate my unit test code from my other code.

I put the test code into one file and the other code into another file in the same directory:

The actual code file:

```
#lang racket
(provide
  ...procedure names...)
...procedures...
```

The test code file:

```
#lang racket
(require rackunit)
(require "...filename of the actual code file...")
...some additional procedures...
...test suite with multiple test cases in it...
```

Then I run:

```
raco test test-code-filename
```

However, this does not work, at the first test case at the first call of a procedure, which is not defined in the test code file, it tells me it is an unbound identifier.

Before this structure, I also tried to use `(module` and `(module+` combinations in the files, but the same issue appeared.

Somehow I don't seem to understand modules correctly from reading the documentation. How can I achieve this split of the code (having it separated in two files)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm... all-defined-out should not be necessary. So, for instance, with

foo.rkt:

```
#lang racket

(provide a)

(define (a x) (add1 x))
```

and bar.rkt:

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit
         "foo.rkt")

;; passing test
(check-equal? (a 9) 10)
;; failing test:
(check-equal? (a 4) 6)
```

... running

`raco test /tmp/bar.rkt`

produces this output:

```
--------------------
FAILURE
actual:     5
expected:   6
name:       check-equal?
location:   (#<path:/tmp/bar.rkt> 9 0 111 22)
expression: (check-equal? (a 4) 6)

Check failure
--------------------
```

... so I'm not sure why your original example didn't work. Sounds like something else was going on.

Comment: I should have made it more clear in my own answer, that I only use `(all-defined-out)` because I really wrote tests for each defined procedure. I didn't want to clutter the code in my answer with all the procedure names. Of course I could have listed them all, but when I did so without the additional parentheses, they were always undefined in my test code. I am not sure why your example works, because this is almost the same as I tried before, except that I did increment with `(+ x 1)`. I'll change my code and check if it works like that again.

Comment: Yes your code structure works. I have no idea what else was going on in my original code, which caused this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I found the answer. Instead of using:

```
(provide
  a
  b
  c ...)
```

I needed to use:

```
(provide (all-defined-out))
```

So there is one additional set of parentheses. So in total I got the following structure working:

```
#lang racket
(provide (all-defined-out))
...procedures...
```

The test code file:

```
#lang racket
(require rackunit)
(require "...filename of the actual code file...")
...some additional procedures...
...test suite with multiple test cases in it...
```

And then:

```
raco test file-with-tests.rkt
```

Works. It still does not print any descriptions in cases of failures, but that is another question.